# Node-gyp npm install getting Build Errors (Had Key errors in MS version previously) on Windows10

Tags: node.js, windows, msbuild, npm-install, node-gyp

Using NPM install -g to install the package with the error log information below on my windows cmd:

```
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\yujiaqian5\app\nvm\npm\node_modules\@leo\core\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "D:\\yujiaqian5\\app\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\yujiaqian5\\app\\nvm\\npm\\node_modules\\@leo\\core\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\yujiaqian5\app\nvm\npm\node_modules\node_modules\utf-8-validate
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v4.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

Previously I've got an 'Key Error: 2017' when I didn't explicitly set my msbuild path, so I reinstalled my visual studio community 2019 and followed this page to set my msbuild path(the msbuild.exe under 2019 file folder), and msversion(2017), https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1753, though this time the key error didn't show up, it made me confused that a new build error occurred without any other explicit info, and I don't understand where exactly it failed...

Changing the msversion by setting config msversion to 2019 didn't solve the problem and would also cause the version error again.

I have tried installing 2017 version and I don't think that worked either.
Does anyone have any idea about the issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by uninstalling everything I had about Visual Studio and re-installing the 2017 version installer, and I re-set the msvs_version and the msbuild_path. 2022 version just won't work for this project so it's really important to find previous version of the build tools (especially the installer) and make sure the path is set to the exact folder where your msbuild.exe is kept. I utilized the 2019 and 2022 installers before to install the build tools of 2017 (NOT THE 2019/2022 version) and also set the path but that just didn't work. The best way to avoid unexpected errors would be using the corresponding installer that would fit your program to build from the very beginning.